# make sharepoint application run on only one server in a two server topology

Tags: sharepoint, load-balancing, sharepoint-2013

Our organization have bought KwizCom's WikiPlus. However, it turns out you can only activate one server per purchase. So we activated only one of them :)

What I'm asking is, can we ensure all of the requests sent to wikiplus app are handled by the server we activated? Can this be done through some load balance setting? Or any other method?

Our farm consists of two load balanced servers that host a number of web applications. Therefore excluding one of the servers from the farm is out of question for us. And we do not want to purchase another license for 3700 something dollars.

Good news is we need wikiplus for only one of the web applications and it will be used by 50 people or so.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Request Manager to accomplish this. It can work with your load balancer and you can configure a rule that looks at the URL and sends matches for WikiPlus requests to a specific WFE.

Here's info on configuration: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj712708.aspx.